# What is the default text color for theme.appcompat.light?

Tags: android

The title says it all, looking for the default color value used in TextViews in theme.appcompat.light

tried looking for it in Android studio by hitting ctrl on theme.appcompat.light but it brought me down a rabbit hole that I couldn't find the end of.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like `theme.appcompat.light` goes all the way up to `Platform.AppCompat.Light`

By default I'm just going to assume you mean the primary color.

Here's what it looks like:

```
<style name="Platform.AppCompat.Light" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

    ...

    <!-- Text colors -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/abc_primary_text_material_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/abc_secondary_text_material_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">@color/abc_secondary_text_material_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/abc_secondary_text_material_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiaryInverse">@color/abc_secondary_text_material_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryDisableOnly">@color/abc_primary_text_disable_only_material_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverseDisableOnly">@color/abc_primary_text_disable_only_material_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/hint_foreground_material_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHintInverse">@color/hint_foreground_material_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/highlighted_text_material_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">?attr/colorAccent</item>

    ...

</style>
```

Inside you'll see `abc_primary_text_material_light`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/primary_text_disabled_material_light"/>
    <item android:color="@color/primary_text_default_material_light"/>
</selector>
```

Which last but not least defines it's color as:

```
<color name="primary_text_default_material_light">#de000000</color>
```